# Is a private move constructor to prevent move?

Tags: c++, c++11

A common pattern in C++ is to make the copy constructor private:

```
class A
{
    public:
        // ...
    private:
        A(const A&);
};
```

But will the following code then compile (in C++11/14):

```
A f();

auto a = f();
```

The standard contains information about automatically generating move constructors. I neither have access to the standard nor a compiler which actually generates move constructors. My question is: do I have to write

```
class A
{
    public:
        // ...
    private:
        A(const A&);
        A(const A&&);
};
```

to prevent moving as well (and operators= analogously)?

Comment: If you write a copy constructor, it doesn't generate a move constructor.

Comment: A user-declared copy ctor prevents generation of the move members.

Comment: Note that the pattern you're referring to is for C++98/03 but is now deprecated in C++11 thanks to the ability to `delete` constructors / assignment operators (eg. `ClassName(ClassName&&) = delete;` to explicitly prevent the implicit move constructor).

Comment: syam: You are right. The reasons I used the old pattern are (i) my compiler does no support it and (ii) I am specifically interested in how C++98 code behaves under C++11.

Comment: I suppose I should have had faith that C++11 did not introduce surprises like this. Everything is as it should.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But will the following code then compile (in C++11/14):

No, it will not. The presence of a user-declared copy constructor should inhibit the implicit generation of a move constructor. Per paragraph 12.8/9 of the C++11 Standard:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>
> — **X does not have a user-declared copy constructor**,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>
> — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

Comment: Great! Once again I am impressed by SO! :-)